# Accessing SQL Assembly in C#project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm using Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll from below location to get the version of sqlserver installed in one version of windows machine(say windows 7).

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

But  the same dll is available under below folder in Windows XP.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies

Since my development box is win7, the dll reference to project is from the first location..but when I run the application in winxp it fails since the location of dll is different in both  the versions of windows..

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should include the dll into your project and have `copy local=true` selected.

Comment: when we do that does it refer from GAC? could you please explain a little more on this.

Comment: Sorry I am not too familiar with GAC, but if you enable `Copy Local` for a referenced assembly in Visual Studio (youre using vs, right?) then that assembly should get copied over to your bin folder (thus avoiding further lookup for the assembly in windows folders).